# Application performance degraded suddenly - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web-applications, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on the ASP.NET application which is used by 10K people approx.
Till last week it was working fine and suddenly from past week it's performance is degraded. Application is taking too long time to respond, also opening each page taking a lot of time(1-2 mins approx.) even though no complex calls or functionality is present.
I have checked all stored procedures in database and all are working fine and their execution time is less than 5 seconds.
Also using SAAS AppDynamics tools I have checked all calls and request-response time in each page of the application, but it seems everything to be fine there also. All calls between application server and data base server are happening in 2-3 seconds.
I am not able to find where exactly the issue is. 
Is there any applicaiton like AppDynamics which can be helpful?

NOTE : I am using linked server in some stored procedures.

Need help in identifying the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any form of error logging? Do you see any timeout errors in those logs?

Comment: Yes..I am maintaining exception log but I cannot find any timeout error in there.

Comment: Any other services your website is connected to? caching or webapi? check you've enough sql connections availble in connection pool and connections are freed up after use?

Comment: Yes I am calling one service for authentication purpose. Also I have created new application pool and hosted application there but still issue is there. And yes I am closing and disposing all connections after using them.

Comment: Perhaps this might be obvious, but did you Update the Application in that timeframe? You could try it with a previous version and see if you can reproduce this if that was the case.
Did you check your network activity and other resources?

Comment: Yes I have updated the application also I tried with previous version of the application but the issue is same. Network utilization and RAM utilization on the server is normal. Also I have added 4 cores to the application server but there is no change in performance. However other application hosted in same application server are working fine.

Comment: The next thing that comes into mind, are table or other locks. Perhaps some requests have to wait for a table or some data to get unlocked again after something has been performed? Do you have any non-shareable-resources? Also, if i remember correctly, if the ASP.NET Application restarts (for whatever reason), requests could take longer (warmup). Can you check how often this happens?

Comment: Have you checked the fragmentation of the indexes in the database?

Comment: But I am using SAAS AppDynamics..there I cannot find any thing worong in there @KampfFussel

Comment: I have not checked from the point of fragmentation but all queries and stored procedures are getting executed in less than 4-5 seconds. @Andrea

Comment: @Andrea I have checked fragmentation point and found that tables which are mostly used are having average fragmentation in range of 80% to 99%(which is bad) and average page space used for these tables ranges from 65% to 99%(might be bit good). Page count for these tables ranges from 400(min) to 23K(max).

Comment: Would anybody like to he me in here? It will be very helpful. @Andrea